# ImageMagick: crop but keep original canvas size and paint background white

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation, imagemagick-convert

I want to crop an image into equally sized tiles, but not by separating them, rather by generating subimages where only the crop area remains from the original image and the rest is painted white. The original canvas size remains constant.

By reading the manual, [here in specific](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_equal), I figured I can get easily get equally sized tiles by running:

```sh
convert image.jpg -crop 7x6@ +repage +adjoin image_7x6_%d.jpg
```

This, however, gives me smaller images. I found on the imagemagick board [a post](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=25228) suggesting that painting the outside in white is feasible, but I haven't figured out which command to use to get that working.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it that actually paints the rest of the image a color. You asked for white, but for display purpose, I will use blue.

Here I do it with some Unix shell script.

```
First, crop the image, but do not add +repage or that will remove the virtual canvas.

Save the images as MIFF (or PNG) to preserve the virtual canvas.

Then loop over each one as flatten against your color.

Then remove all the MIFF files.
```

Input:

[image]

```
convert lena.png -crop 2x2@ +adjoin lena_%02d.miff
for img in *.miff; do
name=$(convert $img -format %t info:)
convert $img -background blue -flatten $name.jpg
done
rm -f *.miff
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: great answer. Works perfectly for any number of tiles.

Answer (score 1):

If you tile your image and save the tiles as PNG files, they will *"remember"* their former position on the virtual canvas, so you can simply put them back onto a white canvas the same size.

```
convert -size 160x100 xc:red -crop 2x2@ frame-%d.png
```

Now look at tiles, specifically 4th column:

```
identify fra*.png
frame-0.png PNG 80x50 160x100+0+0 8-bit sRGB 2c 308B 0.000u 0:00.000
frame-1.png PNG 80x50 160x100+80+0 8-bit sRGB 2c 308B 0.000u 0:00.000
frame-2.png PNG 80x50 160x100+0+50 8-bit sRGB 2c 308B 0.000u 0:00.000
frame-3.png PNG 80x50 160x100+80+50 8-bit sRGB 2c 308B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish that in a single command using ImageMagick v6 or v7, on Windows or *nix, and without writing any intermediate files with a command like this...

```
convert image.jpg -fill white \
   \( +clone -colorize 100 -write mpr:bg +delete \) \
   -crop 7x6@ -set geometry +%[fx:s.page.x]+%[fx:s.page.y] \
   mpr:bg null: +insert +insert -layers composite image_7x6_%d.jpg
```

That is in *nix shell syntax using IM v6. For Windows change the continued line backslashes "\" to carets "^", and remove the backslash escapes "\(...\)" from the parentheses "(...)".

For IM v7 change "convert" to "magick".

Edited to add: As Fred points out in the comment below, the cropped pieces already contain the geometry of their original locations on the canvas. The command can be simplified to something more like this...

```
convert image.jpg \
   \( +clone -fill white -colorize 100 -write mpr:bg +delete \) \
   -crop 7x6@ mpr:bg null: +insert +insert -layers composite image_7x6_%d.jpg
```

Comment: Neat use of +insert twice to rotate the image sequence. I had tried doing something similar, but without the +inserts it failed. However, your command does not need the -set geometry .... This works fine for me on my Mac:  `convert lena.jpg \( +clone -fill white -colorize 100 -write mpr:bg +delete \) -crop 2x2@ mpr:bg null: +insert +insert -layers composite image_7x6_%d.jpg`